# Google OR-Tools doesn't find solution on VRPtw problem

Tags: or-tools

I'm tackling with VRPtw problem and struggling that the solver finds no solution with any data except for artificial small one.

The setting is as below.
There are several depots and locations to visit. Each locations have the time-window. Each vehicles have break time and work time. Also, the locations have some constraints and only the vehicles which satisfy that demand can visit there.

Based on this experiment setting, I wrote the code below.
As I wrote, it looks that it is working with small artificial data, but with real data, it never found the solution. I tried with 5 different data sets.
Although I set the 7200 sec time limit, previously I ran for longer than 10 hours and it was same.
The data's scale is 40~50 vehicles and 200~300 locations.
Does this code have a problem? If not, on what kind of order, should I change the approach(such as initialization, searching method and so on)?

(Edited to use integer for time matrix)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Tuple

from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2

# TODO: Refactor
BIG_ENOUGH = 100000000
TIME_DIMENSION = 'Time'
TIME_LIMIT = 7200


@dataclass
class DataSet:
    time_matrix: List[List[int]]
    locations_num: int
    vehicles_num: int
    vehicles_break_time_window: List[Tuple[int, int, int]]
    vehicles_work_time_windows: List[Tuple[int, int]]
    location_time_windows: List[Tuple[int, int]]
    vehicles_depots_indices: List[int]
    possible_vehicles: List[List[int]]


def execute(data: DataSet):
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(data.locations_num,
                                           data.vehicles_num,
                                           data.vehicles_depots_indices,
                                           data.vehicles_depots_indices)

    routing_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingModelParameters()
    routing_parameters.solver_parameters.trace_propagation = True
    routing_parameters.solver_parameters.trace_search = True

    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager, routing_parameters)

    def time_callback(source_index, dest_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(source_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(dest_index)
        return data.time_matrix[from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        BIG_ENOUGH,
        BIG_ENOUGH,
        False,
        TIME_DIMENSION)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(TIME_DIMENSION)

    # set time window for locations start time
    # set condition restrictions
    possible_vehicles = data.possible_vehicles
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data.location_time_windows):
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx + data.vehicles_num)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
        routing.SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex(possible_vehicles[location_idx], index)

    solver = routing.solver()
    for i in range(data.vehicles_num):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))

    # set work time window for vehicles
    for vehicle_index, work_time_window in enumerate(data.vehicles_work_time_windows):
        start_index = routing.Start(vehicle_index)

        time_dimension.CumulVar(start_index).SetRange(work_time_window[0],
                                                      work_time_window[0])

        end_index = routing.End(vehicle_index)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(end_index).SetRange(work_time_window[1],
                                                    work_time_window[1])

    # set break time for vehicles
    node_visit_transit = {}
    for n in range(routing.Size()):
        if n >= data.locations_num:
            node_visit_transit[n] = 0
        else:
            node_visit_transit[n] = 1

    break_intervals = {}

    for v in range(data.vehicles_num):
        vehicle_break = data.vehicles_break_time_window[v]
        break_intervals[v] = [
            solver.FixedDurationIntervalVar(vehicle_break[0],
                                            vehicle_break[1],
                                            vehicle_break[2],
                                            True,
                                            'Break for vehicle {}'.format(v))
        ]
        time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(
            break_intervals[v], v, node_visit_transit
        )

    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)

    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GREEDY_DESCENT)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = TIME_LIMIT
    search_parameters.log_search = True

    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    return solution


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = DataSet(
        time_matrix=[[0, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6],
                     [0, 0, 6, 4, 5, 5],
                     [1, 3, 0, 6, 5, 4],
                     [2, 1, 6, 0, 5, 4],
                     [2, 2, 5, 5, 0, 6],
                     [3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0]],
        locations_num=6,
        vehicles_num=2,
        vehicles_depots_indices=[0, 1],
        vehicles_work_time_windows=[(720, 1080), (720, 1080)],
        vehicles_break_time_window=[(720, 720, 15), (720, 720, 15)],
        location_time_windows=[(735, 750), (915, 930), (915, 930), (975, 990)],
        possible_vehicles=[[0], [1], [0], [1]]
    )
    solution = execute(data)
    if solution is not None:
        print("solution is found")
```

Comment: Without the data, nobody can experiment with your code

Comment: True. I edited the post and added the artificial fixture.
Also, I added the information of actual data's size scale.

Comment: your time matrix must return integers not floating point values...

Comment: Oh, sorry. When I re-wrote the artificial fixture manually, I mistook and wrote with float.
On the actual data, they are integers.